# Truffle framework with storage

Tags: storage, swarm, framework, ipfs, truffle

How can I integrate truffle with swarm or ipfs for permanent document storage?
Are there any libraries?

Comment: did you get an exact answer to this question, if yes then can you share a reference link?

Answer (score 2):

Truffle is a build tool for Ethereum projects. If you want to use swarm or ipfs in your Truffle project just add them to the `package.json` file of the generated project.

Truffle has support for custom deploy scripts where you can optimize your deployment process for swarm and ipfs.

Comment: Can you give some examples where I can read more on the subject?