# How to use IPFS with truffle framework

Tags: truffle, ipfs

How to use IPFS to get the hash of the document and store it on private blockchain (using go-ethereum )? consider truffle framework and solidity as contract oriented language.

Comment: A detailed description will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you, it is a  [similar question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/4599/12087) . On a note you can try using Embark framework to develop a dApp. I have done the same kind of dApp using Embark.